# Webpack bundle and TypeScript yields wrong global variable format

Tags: javascript, module, typescript, webpack

I am using TypeScript with CommonJS module output and webpack to create a browser bundle, using `libraryTarget: 'var'` in webpack so that my library will be available as a global variable 'Foo'. However, instead of the global variable being my default exported class, the global variable will be a wrapper, and I have to call `new Foo.default()` to actually instantiate my default exported class.

Here is a minimal TypeScript example:

```
export default class Foo {}
```

After compilation, this will be the plain JS result:

```
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
    }
    return Foo;
})();
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.default = Foo;
```

Relevant webpack.config.js section:

```
output:
    {
        library: 'Foo',
        libraryTarget: 'var'
    }
```

Now, when including the bundle in a `<script>` tag, I can tell from the debugger that the global variable `Foo` is a wrapper, and the constructor function of `Foo` is actually a the property `default`, so I need to call:

```
var foo_instance = new Foo.default();
```

But I expect it to be:

```
var foo_instance = new Foo();
```

I already found out that if I change in the TS compilation output the line `exports.default = Foo` into `module.exports = Foo` then I can call `new Foo()` just as I would expect.

So, how can I use webpack the right way so that my constructor function is not wrapped in the `default` property?

Answer (score -1):

I expect that you are using Babel.
So your problem is the default behaviour in Babel 6. It doesn't export default `module.exports` anymore.

Please look at the following Babel plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports

Comment: Downvote as the questions HEADLINE clearly states I am using TypeScript as a transpiler, **not** Babel.